# Sorting TableView columns: a way to bypass an "unsorted" mode

Tags: java, javafx-2

Here's another JavaFX question I was hoping to get an answer to.  Currently, when you sort a column in TableView, you get ascending order from the first click, descending from the second click, and on a third click it does nothing and the sorting arrow disappears.  I understand that the third sorting mode should return the column back to its previous, unsorted state.  I know that this mode has been added recently due to popular requests, but is there a way to completely bypass it?  That is, on the first click we sort in ascending order, on a second click we sort in descending order, and that's it, the third click will be ascending order again?  Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: I've tried to find a solution but I didn't. Please let us know if you've found a hack!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a ChangeListener to the column?

```
column.sortTypeProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.SortType>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.SortType> observable,
                final javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.SortType oldValue, final javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.SortType newValue) {
            if (oldValue==javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING) {
                column.sortTypeProperty().set(javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING);
            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**: since the code above doesn't work (see comment) I suggest the following:

```
Button columnHeader = new Button("column name");
columnHeader.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (column.getSortType()==SortType.DESCENDING) {
                column.setSortType(SortType.ASCENDING);
            }
        }
    });
column.setGraphic(columnHeader);
```

Comment: That does not work because the listener is not triggered if the user clicks the header for every third time.

Comment: Ok, then the only solution I can think of is to listen to each click on the column. This can be archieved by setting the graphic of the column header like column.setGraphic(new Button("columnName")); and adding an ActionListener to this Button.

Comment: You can edit your answer with this information, so I can upvote it back to 0. Thx.

Comment: I gave it a try, but it seems that the logic is missing something.  The sort type is set just fine but the sort itself is not happening, the column data stays as it it.

Comment: Did you set **column.setSortable(true);** ?

Comment: Yes, it's set after I define sort type.

Answer (score 0):

As of current JFX API, The only solution to this is as follows:
Create new class called *MyTableView* which extends *TableView* , and now you can override its existing sort() method as per your convenience. On third click, list *sortOrder* will return nothing and its size will be zero. At this point, you can track count, if it is third click. Please refer a small code attached.

```
public class MyTableView<S>  extends TableView {
    private int countHeaderClick = -1 ;

    @Override
    public void sort(){
        final ObservableList<? extends TableColumn<S,?>> sortOrder = getSortOrder();

        countHeaderClick++ ;
        super.sort();
        if(sortOrder.size() > 0) {
            columnClicked = sortOrder.get(0).getId(); // name of column clicked

            strSortTypeValue = sortOrder.get(0).getSortType().toString(); // ascending or descending

        }else{
           <what ever you want to perform>
        }
}
```

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Doesn't work. Unknown variables - `columnClicked`, `strSortTypeValue` ... I guess those might be super class variables. But in JFX2 - No.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty solution for this problem:

```
// global variables
TableView<Object> table;
TableColumn currentSortColumn;

void initialize() {
  // set default sort column
  currentSortColumn = table.getColumns().get(0);
  table.getSortOrder().setAll(currentSortColumn);

  // update current sort column after sorting changes
  for (TableColumn column : table.getColumns()) {
    column.sortTypeProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      currentSortColumn = column;
    });
  }
  // if table loses comparator restore the sort order!
  table.comparatorProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue == null) {
      table.getSortOrder().setAll(currentSortColumn);
      if (currentSortColumn.getSortType().equals(TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING)) {
        currentSortColumn.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
      } else {
        currentSortColumn.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sortOrder property on TableView is responsible for holding the columns that are shown as sorted.
With this in mind to ensure a column is always sorted this property can be observed and whenever it is found to not contain the column (such as on the 'third click') then just add it back through a listener as so:

```
TableColumn<?,?> aColumnThatMustAlwaysBeSorted = ...;

tableView.getSortOrder().addListener( (ListChangeListener<? super TableColumn<?,?>>)observable -> {
    if( !tableView.getSortOrder().contains(aColumnThatMustAlwaysBeSorted) ){
        aColumnThatMustAlwaysBeSorted.setSortType(SortType.ASCENDING);
        tableView.getSortOrder().add(aColumnThatMustAlwaysBeSorted);
    }
});

getSortOrder().add(aColumnThatMustAlwaysBeSorted);
```

The behaviour when shift clicking multiple columns for sorting can seem a bit unusual at first as on clicking another column the 'always-sorted' column will become the second sort index and any further columns will append after it. If the user wants it further down the index then shift clicking the 'always-sorted' column will again force it to be appended as the last sort index.